# approximate equation for temperature drop near wall in contact with fluid

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, heat-transfer, cfd, thermal-conduction

I am concerned about the following problem and so far I am not able to find a solution. Let us consider an environment at a temperature $T_a$ and the inner surface of a not insulating wall in contact with it. The goal is to find a physical law in order to discover how $T_a$ approaches the wall temperature $T_{wh}$.
Note that, assuming there is convective heat transfer between the environment and the wall, we have the boundary condition $ -k \frac{d T_{wh}} {dx} = h (T_a - T_{wh})$.
In particular, referring to the picture, what I need is the temperature trend between the fluid $T_a$ and $T_{wh}$. I guess it is something related to boundary layers which regulates this trend, but I am really struggling finding at least an empirical. Any help or reference to look at is apprecciated.
Technically speaking my goal is to estimate $T_{wh}$ knowing $T_a$

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a good reference, such as Simonson: Heat Transfer would be a good read / start.

Comment: If your goal is just to estimate $T_{wh}$ from $T_a$, you will need a heat transfer coefficient. Finding physical law for this is not easy and equations used in practice are usually empirical in some way.